# How to get product image label outside the gallery?

Tags: php, image, magento

i'm looking for a way to get image label without having to fetch the whole product mediaGallery.
By default, here is how Magento does it :

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And what I want to do is something that :

```
$_product->someimageattribute->getLabel()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example from `catalog/product/list.phtml`.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. We're almost there : it works fine on default attribute (image, small_image and thumbnail), but I don't get the label for other images : I have the product name instead. Any idea?

Comment: @Jonathan If we want to access image label in custom phtml file.Then what to do?

Comment: @muk you need to provide a lot more information than that comment. please start a new question.

Comment: I got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991565/how-do-i-get-all-the-gallery-images-for-a-product-in-magento-with-a-particular-n

Comment: If you are outside of a template file you can use this piece of code: 
`$product->getData('small_image_label');`. Replace `small_image` by other image types.