# How do I get all the gallery images for a product in magento with a particular name?

Tags: magento

I want to get the image labeled as special from the Gallery images of a product.Using this I want to get that image url.

I tried following code for the same but not working for me

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','look')->getFile();  ?>
```

this was throwing error for me for method getFile()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get product image with specific label from this way

```
$image= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid)->getMediaGalleryImages();
 $_images = $image->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'YOUR_LABEL');
```

http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/get-product-image-from-label-magento.html

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: How do make YOUR_LABEL case insensitive, this can be any case.Should I pass this as an array?